# Seeking floorplan for college, university, large school, government offices, shopping mall, hosptial, etc

Tags: geospatial

I need some data for a digital signage demo project. Preferably something with multiple floors, even multiple buildings, which can be categorized (e.g history/computing/arts dept. Or types of shop or office).

This is so I can have a nice fancy demo. Show all shoe shops, or computer lecture halls, all licensing offices), plus search for individual shops, people, etc, maybe show opening hours, menus for restaurants, how to get there ...

... but, I digress. I just want a floorplan.